# Can I use a DAC with an L293D driver?

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I'm trying to provide analog control to a Bluetooth controlled car, via Arduino. I have joystick app (as the pot).
It send values between 0 to 255
So I'm thinking... Whether this flow down here  will work?

Joystick app --> Bluetooth Rx --> DAC --> Vs pin of L293D. Or motor?

Is Arduino required at all? Or is the serial word enough to translate into voltage via DAC?

Comment: You need a PWM signal for a motor driver, not a DAC.

Comment: @Majenko but I am using a simple dc motor not any servo or stepper motor

Comment: So? What difference does that make? A motor driver *requires* PWM. A DAC (unless it's a very expensive industrial one designed for the purpose) *cannot* directly drive a motor.

Comment: @Majenko that's what... I mean to use the output of the DAC to use with the "motor voltage" pin of l293d.

Comment: What "motor voltage" pin? If you mean the pair of VCC pins, I reiterate: *a DAC cannot drive a motor*.

Comment: @Majenko I totally agree that Kotor requires l293D to be driven. I agree.

Comment: @Majenko the thing is, the DAC provides variable voltage at its output depending on input bits? Right? So this voltage I'm planning to apply to the Vss pin or the motor voltage pin if l293d. So my idea was to vary the motor's input voltage through l293d via DAC. The variable voltage will alter it's rpm also right?

Comment: The power you put into the supply pins of the motor driver is what is used directly by the motor. That supply has to have enough current to drive the motor, which a DAC **cannot** provide. The motor driver is designed to switch a high current supply on and off to the motor. That is how it controls the speed. To use a DAC you will first have to convert that voltage into a PWM waveform to switch the EN pins of the driver so it can switch a high current source to drive the motor. The driver does not magic extra power from thin air.

Comment: @Majenko oh right... So the the current required by the motor is not provided by the DAC(insufficient), unlike a battery supply.

Comment: Correct. You need to amplify that some how, and for a motor the most efficient way is with an H bridge (motor driver) and PWM. There are voltage-to-PWM chips available that would do the job, but you may as well just use an ATTiny and lose the DAC.

Comment: @Majenko so the voltage level at the DAC output, which is determined by input bits, is converted to a pwm waveform. This is fed to en pins to enable that respective motor.

Comment: @Majenko this voltage that varies over say, 8 bits will produce a different waveform for each of the 256 voltage levels? If so, then this will keep on switching the en pin repeatedly depending on wavefrom and thus varying motor speed by determining for how long the motor remains on before giving it another pulse. Right?

Comment: Or you can try power amplifier and weep over all of the power turned into heat on it...

Comment: @NiranjanDixit Correct. But like I say - easier to just use a small MCU and not worry about the complexity of a DAC and PWM chip.

Comment: It seems part of question arises from confusion between the sparse PWM pulses (repeating only about 50 times a second) used as a *command* to radio control hobby servos and speed controls, vs the kind of *continuous* PWM needed to cause a simple H-bridge to directly modulate power to a motor itself.  Essentially the poster will be building their own "ESC" where the high rate continous PWM output is controlled by software and messages originating with bluetooth, rather than controlled by sparse PWM from an RC transmitter.

Comment: Also, consider getting something better than the antiquated L293D, especially if you want to run on batteries.  It is rather horrible, and there are a number of threads discussing better alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. A DAC cannot provide enough current to either directly drive a motor or to power a motor driver (which is basically driving the motor directly through a switch anyway).

A motor driver requires a PWM signal to rapidly switch a high current source on and off to set the motor speed.

You *could* feed the DAC output into the input of a voltage-to-PWM converter chip which would then feed the motor driver's EN pin, but that is pretty pointless when you could just use a small microcontroller to receive the digital speed value and directly generate a PWM signal.

After all, that is the kind of job that small microcontrollers are designed for...